# How to add an index to a postgres table?

Tags: postgresql, vapor

I'm trying to add a column index to a PostgreSQL table using Vapor. I found several tutorial doing this, but none of those code snippets work with the current version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run RAW SQL in migartions like:

```
import FluentPostgreSQL

struct MigrationTest: PostgreSQLMigration {

    static func revert(on conn: PostgreSQLConnection) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
        return conn.future()
    }

    static func prepare(on conn: PostgreSQLConnection) -> Future<Void> {
        return conn.raw("CREATE INDEX test on some_table (field1, field2);").run()
    }
}
```

To add more statements in one migartion, I do it like this:

```
static func prepare(on conn: PostgreSQLConnection) -> Future<Void> {
    let _ = conn.raw("create index if not exists idx_one (field1, field2);").run()  
    let _ = conn.raw("create index if not exists idx_two (field3, field4);").run()

    return conn.future()
}
```

You cant add more statements in one run! For each statement new `let _ = conn.raw().run()`

and in config

```
migrations.add(migration: MigrationTest.self, database: .psql)
```

The advantage of this is that you can add partial indexes etc.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Is it possible to add more than one statement per struct? I get an error when I try to add more SQL statements into the raw. Because I'd have to create a lot of structs and register all of them...

Comment: @G.Marc I have updated the answer with section how to use it with multiple statements in one migration.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there are no possibility to create indexes with Fluent.
In my Vapor3 projects I use my own little extension with raw query
https://gist.github.com/MihaelIsaev/f6442bf3698572cd9170114f236c47c2

You could use it like this

```swift
extension CarBrand: Migration {
    public static func prepare(on connection: Database.Connection) -> Future<Void> {
        return Database.create(self, on: connection) { builder in
            try addProperties(to: builder)
        }.flatMap { _ in
            return connection.addIndexes(\CarBrand.addedByUser, \CarBrand.createdAt)
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: By the way you also could take a look at SwifQL lib for making your own flexible raw queries https://github.com/MihaelIsaev/SwifQL

Comment: Thanks for this solution, but I think I'm going with the raw one as I have more flexibility. Unfortunately, both solutions are not really nice for a framework.

Comment: Raw queries are flexible but not strong typed, that's why I created SwifQL :)